# Is "/etc/issue" common for all Linux distributions?

Tags: login, etc, portability

I'm trying to Create OS detect portable function in bash script,

So I just want to know, the file `"/etc/issue"` is common for all Linux Flavors ?

Comment: In modern distros, there is usually an `/etc/*-release` file with some info.

Comment: `uname` may offer some information too, not sure how accurate a finger print it is.  Don't forget that anyone can modify pretty much anything in a Linux install to obscure the info you want, it'll only find stuff on unmodified installs.

Comment: Yes you are right.., I have selected different option, it will check package manager like `yum` or `apt-get` then it will install packages based on this.

Comment: still I'm working on it check link http://paste.ubuntu.com/5911213/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes this is a standard file across distributions. It's standard on most distros, Fedora/CentOS/RHEL/Debian/Ubuntu etc.

You can read more about it with a [`man issue`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/issue) or its associated file `/etc/issue.net`. You can see the [issue.net man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/issue.net) for more details and how to include macros into both files there as well.

You can also read more about it on the [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) project, [Customizing your Logon with /etc/issue](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/logon.html).

Comment: Is there a Windows equivalent to /etc/issue?

Answer (score 13):

In addition to slm's answer, it's worth remembering that anyone (with root access) can edit the content of `/etc/issue`.  Some organisations may do so to present pre-login warnings or disclaimers, and others may remove all identification of the distribution for security reasons (it doesn't matter how effective either of these measures are).

Therefore, while /etc/issue may exist almost all the time, the content is not necessarily suitable for detecting the OS (as you put it, or more likely, the Linux distribution).

Answer (score 4):

@EightBitTony's answer is correct. Also it does not exist by default on fedora 23.

Do **not** rely on it for identifying random systems. I'd use `/etc/system-release` or `/etc/os-release` but not sure how much universal that is.

Reading a bit `/etc/os-release` comes with `systemd` so I guess won't work with archaic distros (or any that hate `systemd`). Could not find authoritative info about `/etc/system-release`. I guess one has to check many files if compatibility is important. Or use `/etc/os-release` if edge cases are not important.

Comment: More information about `/etc/os-release`: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/os-release.html