# I want to print a line when a user login

Tags: linux, csh

I what to print "you are on an important server" whenever a user(any user) login to a server.

Is the way is to edit each user `.cshrc` file?

Comment: I don't think you want to print that particular line. :)  Edited

Comment: This might help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/265072/ubuntu-linux-12-10-message-of-the-day

Answer (score 4):

Let's not confuse `/etc/motd` with `/etc/issue.net`. The first one is the Linux motd, displayed whenever someone logs in (which includes physical **and** remote connections). The second one, on the other hand, is the default SSH banner file, which is printed along with the motd (actually, before it) whenever a SSH connection is established. When logging into the machine from its physical terminal, the SSH banner will not be displayed.

If you want to change the motd, edit `/etc/motd`. However, it is possible that this file is automatically modified upon boot. Check `/var/run/motd.dynamic` and `/etc/rc.local` for lines than might be editing `/etc/motd`. You might come across some symlinks to the file as well...

If you want to define a SSH banner file, first open your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, and find/set the Banner parameter. The default value is commented :

```
#Banner /etc/issue.net
```

Set your banner file, create it, and place your message in it.

Concerning `/etc/issue`, it is printed if and only if `/etc/issue.net` does not exist. It is displayed on both physical and remote terminals. By the way, on most systems, `/etc/issue*` files are displayed after the boot sequence is complete, but before you login. On remote connections, connection and authentication usually happen one right after the other, hiding the difference between all these files.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at setting up `/etc/issue` or `/etc/motd` files but mostly the former.

When a user logs in `/etc/issue` should be displayed irrespective of the shell the user is using.

See related:

[Is "/etc/issue" common for all Linux distributions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84280/is-etc-issue-common-file)

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the contents of the following files: `/etc/motd` and `/etc/issue.net`. Typically the former file contains messages that are displayed when you locally login through the command line interfaces. The contents of the latter are typically displayed for remote logins.

Here is some sample output from `/etc/issue.net`:

```
cat  /etc/issue.net  
Ubuntu 10.04 LTS
```

And from `/etc/motd`:

```
cat /etc/motd
Linux machine_name 2.6.32-21-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 16 08:10:02 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux
Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Welcome to Ubuntu!
 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
```