# How do I see if the current distro is Arch-based, Debian-based, etc

Tags: shell-script, distributions

I'm writing a shell script that should be able to be used with a variety of Linux distros. I want to see what base the distro is, without hardcoding everything (since there are hundreds of distros), since this script installs packages that are distro-specific (and I need to know which package manager to use). I've seen `/etc/os-release`, but I have heard that some distros don't have that file, or it is in a different format. Also, that won't give me what it's based on.

Thanks!

Comment: Well I said I needed the *base* of the operating system, or at least the package manager.

Answer (score 2):

You could read one or more of these files:

```
/etc/issue

/etc/os-release

/usr/lib/os-release
```

They should be available in most, if not all, distributions (their eventual absence can also be used to identify the distribution).

You can find more details in the answer to [Is "/etc/issue" common for all Linux distributions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84280/is-etc-issue-common-for-all-linux-distributions).